# Intercept outgoing calls and add prefix to phone number

Tags: android

I am currently using a BroadcastReceiver with intent filter "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL".

This allows me to determine the telephone number dialed. However, this also requires the android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permission.

And here is the problem. Google refuses to allow me to upload the app because this permission is critical and is not the main function of my app. OK, this feature is ONE main function, not THE main function.

I have corrected this in the Play Store description. And I have also uploaded an explanation and a video in the Play Console under "App content" - "SMS and Call log permission". I selected the main functions "Default phone handler" and later "proxy calls", both were rejected.

Is there any other way to intercept and prefix calls without android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS?